# Comparing ODI scenarios development vs production

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a list of interfaces, I want to update some mappings in these interfaces but unfortunately our Production and Development environments are not synchronized.

So before editing any interfaces, we need to compare DEV and PROD environments to see, if there is any difference. For some small jobs it is easy to do it manually. But in my case there are more than 100 interfaces and I want to somewhat automatize this process. I need some suggestions on that.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this query against the repository

-- Repository_Object_Changed_by_date -- Here my Work repository User is ODI_WORK_REPO -- ODI version 11 g

```
WITH obj as(
SELECT i_package i_instance, i_folder, NULL i_project, pack_name obj_name,3200 obj_type, 'Package' obj_type_name, last_date, last_user FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.SNP_PACKAGE
 UNION ALL
SELECT i_pop i_instance, i_folder, NULL i_project, pop_name obj_name,3100 obj_type, 'Interface' obj_type_name, last_date, last_user FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.SNP_POP
 UNION ALL
SELECT i_trt i_instance, i_folder, i_project, trt_name obj_name,3600 obj_type, CASE trt_type WHEN 'U' THEN 'Procedure' ELSE 'Knowledge Module' END obj_type_name, last_date, last_user FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.SNP_TRT
 UNION ALL
SELECT i_var i_instance,  NULL i_folder, i_project, var_name obj_name, 3500 obj_type, 'Variable' obj_type_name, last_date, last_user FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.SNP_VAR t
 UNION ALL
SELECT i_table i_instance, i_sub_model i_folder, i_mod i_project, table_name obj_name, 2400 obj_type, 'Table' obj_type_name, last_date, last_user from ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_table t
)
,fd (i_folder, i_project, folder_name, folder_path, lv) AS(
SELECT i_folder, i_project, folder_name, folder_name folder_path, 1 lv
  FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_folder
 WHERE par_i_folder IS NULL
 UNION ALL
SELECT tf.i_folder, tf.i_project, tf.folder_name, fd.folder_path||'\'||tf.folder_name, fd.lv+1
  FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_folder tf JOIN fd
    ON fd.i_folder = tf.par_i_folder
)
,mpl as (
SELECT sm.i_smod i_mc, 'sm' typemc, COALESCE(sm.i_smod_parent,sm.i_mod) i_mp, NVL2(sm.i_smod_parent,'sm','m') typemp, sm.smod_name name --, m.i_mod_folder
  FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_sub_model sm
 UNION ALL
SELECT i_mod, 'm' typ, i_mod_folder, 'mf', mod_name
  FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_model m
 UNION ALL
SELECT i_mod_folder, 'mf', par_i_mod_folder, 'mf', mod_folder_name FROM ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_mod_folder
)
,mp (i_mc, typemc, i_mp, typemp, model_tech, model_path, lv) AS(
SELECT i_mc, typemc, i_mp, typemp, name tname, name model_path, 1 lv
  FROM mpl
 WHERE i_mp IS NULL
 UNION ALL
SELECT mpl.i_mc, mpl.typemc, mpl.i_mp, mpl.typemp, mp.model_tech, mp.model_path||'\'||mpl.name model_path, mp.lv+1 lv
  FROM mpl JOIN mp
    ON mpl.i_mp = mp.i_mc AND mpl.typemp=mp.typemc
)
SELECT obj.i_instance, OBJ_NAME, CASE WHEN COALESCE(project_name,mp.model_tech) IS NULL THEN 'Global ' || OBJ_TYPE_NAME ELSE OBJ_TYPE_NAME END obj_type_name
      ,obj.last_date
      ,obj.last_user
      ,COALESCE(project_name,mp.model_tech) project_model
      ,COALESCE(fd.folder_path,mp.model_path) path  
  FROM obj
  FULL OUTER
  JOIN fd
    ON fd.i_folder = obj.i_folder AND obj_type_name!='Table'
  FULL OUTER
  JOIN mp
    ON mp.i_mc = obj.i_folder AND obj_type_name='Table'
  FULL OUTER
  JOIN ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_project p
    ON p.i_project = COALESCE(obj.i_project, fd.i_project)
  FULL OUTER
  JOIN ODI_WORK_REPO.snp_model m
    ON m.i_mod = obj.i_project
```